# Python class: create a unique copy of a class-level variable inside a class function

Tags: python, multithreading, class, variables

I have a class with a dictionary variable called 'order_book'. That variable is updated by a single thread but I'm trying to do operations on it in a separate thread as well. The function running in the separate thread looks like the following:

```
while True:
    ob = self.order_book
    for x in ob:
        #do stuff
```

However this regularly produces a RunTimeError due to the dictionary changing size during the operation (because the other thread is removing or adding old /new orders). How is it that the local variable 'ob' is only referring back to the class level variable self.order_book and isn't creating a unique local copy of the dictionary?

Comment: It just points towards the actual dictionary wherever it is, maybe try `ob = dict(self.order_book)`

Comment: That makes sense - I need to first do an operation on the dictionary to establish a new variable. Thanks Peter!

Comment: This has nothing to do with classes. This is how assignment *always works* in Python. Assignment **never copies in Python**. Read Ned Batchelder's [Facts and Myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: You don't need a variable, you need a copy of the value (see @Peter's suggestion)